# Customize Scrolling indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to customize scrolling indicator(vertical or horizontal) in UIScrollView. For example, change it's color or position in scrollview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to uncheck showVerticalIndicator and showHorizontallIndicator in the Interface Builder.

Then in the `viewDidLoad` method add :

```
[super viewDidLoad];    
self.scrollViewBarImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *imgBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scroller.png"];
[self.scrollViewBarImgView setImage:imgBar];
CGRect frame = scrollViewBarImgView.frame;
frame.size.width = 8;
frame.size.height = 60;
frame.origin.x = 312;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[self.scrollViewBarImgView setFrame:frame];

[self.tableView addSubview:scrollViewBarImgView];
```

then in the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll` method :

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
CGRect frame = self.scrollViewBarImgView.frame;

float fact = (cellHeight*numberOfRow+ indicatorBarHeight) / tableViewHeight;

frame.origin.y = offset.y + (offset.y/fact);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[self.scrollViewBarImgView setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is working for me.